# How to read multi-byte values with ctypes

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I want to read two consecutive 24 bit values from a bytes object, using ctypes Structure and Union. This would be 6 bytes.

Unfortunately, ctypes reads 32 bits per value. 
Also, `sizeof` reports the Structure as bigger than expected.

Using `_pack_ = 1` did not bring the expected result.

An example with a minimal Structure and a binary example value:

```py
import unittest
import ctypes

SixBytes = ctypes.c_uint8 * 6

class MultiBits(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_uint, 24),
        ("y", ctypes.c_uint, 24),
    ]

class Multi(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("bits", MultiBits),
        ("asbytes", SixBytes),
    ]

class TestMultibyte(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(ctypes.sizeof(MultiBits), 6)

    def test_multibyte(self):
        data = b'\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x02'
        parser = Multi()
        parser.asbytes = SixBytes(*data)
        self.assertEqual(parser.bits.x, 257)
        self.assertEqual(parser.bits.y, 258)
```

I would have expected `sizeof(MultiBits)` to be `6` and the values to be parsed correctly.

Instead, `sizeof(MultiBits)` is reported as `8` and `parser.bits.y` is  256 times the expected result.

Am I doing or expecting something wrong?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to call some function in a C library or just to get two 24 bit integers from a bytes object into Python integers?

Comment: I just try to decode binary data, that comes from an arbitrary source. (Mostly decoded from base64)

Comment: I tend to use [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) for these operations, especially since you can customize the number of bits per word. See the [packing page](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/packing.html) for more details on that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `int.from_bytes` to decode 24 bits (3 bytes) at a time.

```
data = b'\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x02'
[int.from_bytes(data[i:i+3], byteorder='little', signed=False) for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
>>> [65792, 131328]
```

The integers are unsigned as in your code and I'm guessing the byte order to be little-endian, although it looks like your tests are assuming big-endian.

Comment: You are totally right using `int.from_bytes`. I am parsing a bigger data structure though, where the descriptive approach of ctypes would come in handy.

Comment: It looks like neither `ctypes` nor `struct.unpack` permits that. You might have to resort to a combination of one of those with `int.from_bytes', where you first take the odd length ints out as uint_8 arrays or unsigned char, and then convert those to int. FWIW I just tried data type 'i3' in numpy and it doesn't like it either.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a bitfield in a structure, the size of the bitfield is always going to be a multiple of the type used by the bitfield...in this case, `c_int` (4 bytes).  24 bits can't fit in 4 bytes, so you get 8 bytes.  You have to stick to 8-bit types to fit 24 bits without padding.

Here's a way to get what you want using properties instead of bitfields.  BTW, kudos providing unit tests!!! I added one to test the property setters...

```
import unittest
import ctypes

SixBytes = ctypes.c_uint8 * 6

class MultiBits(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("_data", SixBytes)]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return int.from_bytes(self._data[:3],'big')

    @x.setter
    def x(self,value):
        self._data[:3] = value.to_bytes(3,'big')

    @property
    def y(self):
        return int.from_bytes(self._data[3:],'big')

    @y.setter
    def y(self,value):
        self._data[3:] = value.to_bytes(3,'big')

class Multi(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("bits", MultiBits),
                ("asbytes", SixBytes)]

class TestMultibyte(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(ctypes.sizeof(MultiBits), 6)

    def test_multibyte(self):
        data = b'\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x02'
        parser = Multi()
        parser.asbytes = SixBytes(*data)
        self.assertEqual(parser.bits.x, 257)
        self.assertEqual(parser.bits.y, 258)

    def test_setbits(self):
        data = b'\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x02'
        parser = Multi()
        parser.asbytes = SixBytes(*data)
        parser.bits.x = 0xABCDEF
        parser.bits.y = 0x123456
        self.assertEqual(bytes(parser.asbytes),b'\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```