# How to have non aligned python Ctypes structures on 24 bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to have a python representation of some structures.
All is good when using bitfields and the size of the final struct is 4 bytes (or bigger).
When it comes to a structure that has one single value represented on 24 bit (3 bytes) a padding of 1 byte is added when using bitfield syntax, but it is not added when I use an array (see code below).

```
from ctypes import *

class MyStructure(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("vol", c_uint32, 24)
    ]
    _pack_ = 1

class MyStructure2(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("vol", c_uint8 * 3)
    ]
    _pack_ = 1


c = MyStructure()
c.vol = 0xABCDEF

print(bytes(c)) # should be 24 bit 
print(len(bytes(c))) # should be 3

d = MyStructure2()
d.vol[0] = 0xAB
d.vol[1] = 0xCD
d.vol[2] = 0xEF

print(bytes(d)) # it is24 bit 
print(len(bytes(d))) # it is 3
```

Output is:

```
$ python test.py
b'\xab\xcd\xef\x00'
4
b'\xab\xcd\xef'
3
```

How should I modify the first structure to have size a 3 bytes ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done, because a 24-bit int is not a basic type. However, here is a recipe how to read 3 bytes (24 bits, your `MyStructure2`) as an int: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048493/5378816 I tried `int.from_bytes(d.vol, byteorder='big', signed=False` and it worked.

Comment: Just as another data point, you would find the same thing to be true in C.  If you define a bitfield structure with 24 bits, it will occupy 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a bit field, but you can make it appear to work with the byte array using a property. Note that a C structure with a bitfield of `int32_t value:24;` will also be four bytes, even with packing, so be sure your structure sizes match up.

```py
from ctypes import *

class MyStructure(BigEndianStructure):

    _fields_ = ("_vol", c_uint8 * 3),

    @property
    def vol(self):
        return int.from_bytes(self._vol, 'big')

    @vol.setter
    def vol(self, value):
        self._vol = tuple(value.to_bytes(3, 'big'))

c = MyStructure()
c.vol = 0xABCDEF

print(bytes(c)) # should be 24 bit 
print(len(bytes(c))) # should be 3
print(hex(c.vol))
```

Output:

```
b'\xab\xcd\xef'
3
0xabcdef
```

Comment: You can avoid the `tuple`ing by using slice-assignment, `self._vol[:] = value.to_bytes(3, 'big')`

Comment: @ShadowRanger `self._vol = *value.to_bytes(3, 'big'),` and `self_vol = (c_uint8 * 3)(*.value.to_bytes(3, 'big'))` also work.  Lots of methods I just picked one.  Annoying it doesn't just take a byte string.